Assign categorical column based on maximum value in group where other value is non-null
Suppose that a polars DataFrame df contains a set of columns group_cols, and then 2 other columns col1, col2.
I want to add a new column to this called category which takes values either 'primary' or 'secondary'. There should be exactly one occurrence of 'primary' per group in group_cols, and it should be chosen where col1 is maximal BUT col2 is not null. (But if col2 is always null, then it should simply be chosen where col1 is maximal).
So e.g. if we have in the same group 4 rows with values:

col1 = 2, col2 = None
col1 = 1, col2 = 'not null'
col1 = 1, col2 = 'not null also'
col1 = 0, col2 = 'not null either'

then either the 2nd or 3rd row in the group (it does not matter which, but only one of them) should have their category column value as 'primary' and the rest should take values 'secondary' in this column.
I can do this with pandas quite easily by the following:
def assign_category(group):
    if group['col2'].notnull().any():
        max_col1_row = group.loc[group['col2'].notnull(), 'col1'].idxmax()
        category_column = pd.Series('secondary', index=group.index)
        if max_col1_row is not None:
            category_column[max_col1_row] = 'primary'
    else:
        max_col1_row = group['col1'].idxmax()
        category_column = pd.Series('secondary', index=group.index)
        category_column[max_col1_row] = 'primary'
    return category_column

df['category'] = df.groupby('group_cols').apply(assign_category).reset_index(drop=True)

and here is a reproducible example:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group_cols': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'col1': [2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, None, 4, 4, 1],
    'col2': [None, 'not null', 'also not null', 'not null either', 'not null', 'not null', None, None, None, None, None]
})

becomes
pd.DataFrame({'group_cols': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
 'col1': [2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, nan, 4.0, 4.0, 1.0],
 'col2': [None,
  'not null',
  'also not null',
  'not null either',
  'not null',
  'not null',
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None],
 'category': ['secondary',
  'primary',
  'secondary',
  'secondary',
  'primary',
  'secondary',
  'secondary',
  'secondary',
  'primary',
  'secondary',
  'secondary']})

But I am struggling to even start replicating this kind of logic in polars, let alone without making use of the discouraged map_groups.

Why is the third-to-last category 'primary' when col2 is null there?

@BallpointBen Good point, I did not explain what to do for this edge case, I have added to the question to make it clearer. Basically if all instances of col2 are null within a group, the 'primary' row should be chosen where col1 is the maximum of the group

You can use the following (thanks to jqurious for pointing out how this can be done with a single over):
# %%
import polars as pl
from IPython.display import display

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group_cols": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"],
        "col1": [2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, None, 4, 4, 1],
        "col2": [
            None,
            "not null",
            "also not null",
            "not null either",
            "not null",
            "not null",
            None,
            None,
            None,
            None,
            None,
        ],
    }
)

df = df.with_columns(
    category=pl.when(pl.col("col2").is_null().all())
    .then(
        pl.when(pl.int_range(pl.len()) == pl.col("col1").arg_max())
        .then(pl.lit("primary"))
        .otherwise(pl.lit("secondary"))
    )
    .when(
        pl.int_range(pl.len())
        == pl.arg_where(
            pl.col("col1") == pl.col("col1").filter(pl.col("col2").is_not_null()).max()
        ).first()
    )
    .then(pl.lit("primary"))
    .otherwise(pl.lit("secondary"))
    .over(["group_cols"])
)

with pl.Config(tbl_rows=-1):
    display(df)

This acts first on groups, where col2 is entirely null, choosing the first max value. For the other groups, it takes the first max value where col2 is non null.
shape: (11, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────────────────┬───────────┐
│ group_cols ┆ col1 ┆ col2            ┆ category  │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---             ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ i64  ┆ str             ┆ str       │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ A          ┆ 2    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ not null        ┆ primary   │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ also not null   ┆ secondary │
│ A          ┆ 0    ┆ not null either ┆ secondary │
│ B          ┆ 3    ┆ not null        ┆ primary   │
│ B          ┆ 2    ┆ not null        ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 3    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ null ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ primary   │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 1    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
└────────────┴──────┴─────────────────┴───────────┘


There's probably quite a few ways to go about this.
This is what came to mind:
non_null_max = pl.col("col1").filter(pl.col("col2").is_not_null()).max()
is_max = pl.col("col1") == non_null_max.fill_null(pl.col("col1").max())

df.with_columns(category = 
   pl.when((is_max & is_max.is_first_distinct()).over("group_cols"))
     .then(pl.lit("primary"))
     .otherwise(pl.lit("secondary"))
)

shape: (11, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────────────────┬───────────┐
│ group_cols ┆ col1 ┆ col2            ┆ category  │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---             ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ i64  ┆ str             ┆ str       │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ A          ┆ 2    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ not null        ┆ primary   │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ also not null   ┆ secondary │
│ A          ┆ 0    ┆ not null either ┆ secondary │
│ B          ┆ 3    ┆ not null        ┆ primary   │
│ B          ┆ 2    ┆ not null        ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 3    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ null ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ primary   │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 1    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
└────────────┴──────┴─────────────────┴───────────┘

Breakdown
We get the non-null max per group:
df.with_columns(max = 
   pl.col("col1").filter(pl.col("col2").is_not_null()).max()
     .over("group_cols")
)

shape: (11, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────────────────┬──────┐
│ group_cols ┆ col1 ┆ col2            ┆ max  │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---             ┆ ---  │
│ str        ┆ i64  ┆ str             ┆ i64  │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════════════════╪══════╡
│ A          ┆ 2    ┆ null            ┆ 1    │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ not null        ┆ 1    │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ also not null   ┆ 1    │
│ A          ┆ 0    ┆ not null either ┆ 1    │
│ B          ┆ 3    ┆ not null        ┆ 3    │
│ B          ┆ 2    ┆ not null        ┆ 3    │
│ C          ┆ 3    ┆ null            ┆ null │
│ C          ┆ null ┆ null            ┆ null │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ null │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ null │
│ C          ┆ 1    ┆ null            ┆ null │
└────────────┴──────┴─────────────────┴──────┘

Then fill_null for the case when all values are null:
df.with_columns(max = 
   pl.col("col1").filter(pl.col("col2").is_not_null()).max()
     .fill_null(pl.col("col1").max())
     .over("group_cols")
)

shape: (11, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────────────────┬─────┐
│ group_cols ┆ col1 ┆ col2            ┆ max │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---             ┆ --- │
│ str        ┆ i64  ┆ str             ┆ i64 │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════════════════╪═════╡
│ A          ┆ 2    ┆ null            ┆ 1   │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ not null        ┆ 1   │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ also not null   ┆ 1   │
│ A          ┆ 0    ┆ not null either ┆ 1   │
│ B          ┆ 3    ┆ not null        ┆ 3   │
│ B          ┆ 2    ┆ not null        ┆ 3   │
│ C          ┆ 3    ┆ null            ┆ 4   │
│ C          ┆ null ┆ null            ┆ 4   │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ 4   │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ 4   │
│ C          ┆ 1    ┆ null            ┆ 4   │
└────────────┴──────┴─────────────────┴─────┘

Finally we add .is_first_distinct() to ask: "is the first maximum per group?"

There exists a plethora of possible solutions. Here, I provide one that is inspired by your own solution implemented in pandas.
is_max_not_null = pl.int_range(pl.len()) == pl.when(pl.col("col2").is_not_null()).then(pl.col("col1")).arg_max()
is_max_all_null = (pl.int_range(pl.len()) == pl.col("col1").arg_max()) & (pl.col("col2").is_null().all())

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(
            is_max_not_null | is_max_all_null
        ).then(
            pl.lit("primary")
        ).otherwise(
            pl.lit("secondary")
        ).over("group_cols").alias("category")
    )
)

shape: (11, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────────────────┬───────────┐
│ group_cols ┆ col1 ┆ col2            ┆ category  │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ ---             ┆ ---       │
│ str        ┆ i64  ┆ str             ┆ str       │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ A          ┆ 2    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ not null        ┆ primary   │
│ A          ┆ 1    ┆ also not null   ┆ secondary │
│ A          ┆ 0    ┆ not null either ┆ secondary │
│ B          ┆ 3    ┆ not null        ┆ primary   │
│ B          ┆ 2    ┆ not null        ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 3    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ null ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ primary   │
│ C          ┆ 4    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
│ C          ┆ 1    ┆ null            ┆ secondary │
└────────────┴──────┴─────────────────┴───────────┘

